# Button not laid out against top of relatively positioned container in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-position

I'm building a toggle switch and the head (button) isn't positioned all the way to the top as I'd expect it to be in Firefox. Works fine in Chrome, so maybe has something to do with default browser styles?

Edit: I know how to make it work, I want to know why it happens.

[codepen https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/qBZYZVy](https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/qBZYZVy)

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.toggle-switch')
const toggleSwitchHead = document.querySelector('.head')

function handleToggle(e) {
  toggleSwitch.classList.toggle('active')
}

toggleSwitchHead.addEventListener('click', handleToggle)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

document, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.head {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.rail {
  height: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0.125rem solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.toggle-switch {
  position: relative;
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.toggle-switch.active > .head {
  background-color: #F7941E;
  border-color: #F7841E;
  transform: translateX(1rem);
}

.toggle-switch.active > .rail {
  border: 0.125rem solid #F7941E;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='toggle-switch'>
  <button class='head'></button>
  <div class='rail'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

Add `display:inline-flex;` to **head** class

```
.head{
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

**Click below** to see codepen demo

**[image]**

**Result :**

[image]
[image]

```js
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.toggle-switch')
const toggleSwitchHead = document.querySelector('.head')

function handleToggle(e) {
  toggleSwitch.classList.toggle('active')
}

toggleSwitchHead.addEventListener('click', handleToggle)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

document, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.head {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.rail {
  height: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 0.125rem solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.toggle-switch {
  position: relative;
  height: 1.25rem;
  width: 2rem;
}

.toggle-switch.active > .head {
  background-color: #F7941E;
  border-color: #F7841E;
  transform: translateX(1rem);
}

.toggle-switch.active > .rail {
  border: 0.125rem solid #F7941E;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='toggle-switch'>
  <button class='head'></button>
  <div class='rail'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This breaks it in Chrome and anyway, doesn't explain why it happens.

Comment: try now :) it fixed now worked in chrome and firefox too

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element is what is specifically being rendered differently in Firefox and Chrome.

If you change the `<button>` to a `<div>` the problem fixes itself.

The reason is that the button element is not a `block` element by default. You have to explicitly set the button to be a `block` element to get the desired behavior.

```
.head {
    ...
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

Comment: So why does it having a display of inline-block cause it to not be positioned to the top in a relatively positioned ancestor in Firefox?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome have slightly different implementations of the button element. Chrome resets styles for it that Firefox doesn’t.

Comment: I think it's not the button element specifically but something that has a display of inline-block. Check this out https://codepen.io/warhammered_cat/pen/KKzRgmY. The font and line-height differ in Chrome and Firefox so the height of the body (which contains a button) is different.

Comment: Hmm....interesting behavior on Firefox. If you go to that CodePen and add text to the button, it fixes the issue in Firefox.